# How can i show a jquery popup on PageLoad??

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery to open a popup on Pageload. I guess this is what i should use to show the popup after a button click in an Asp.Net application. How do i get the popup on Pageload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$("#button").click(function(){  

centerPopup();  

loadPopup();  
});  

});
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

centerPopup();  

loadPopup();  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it popup on the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    centerPopup(); 
    loadPopup(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the button click handler if you want to use the same code to load the popup on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

   $("#button").click(function(){  

    centerPopup();  

    loadPopup();  

  }).click();

});
```